# How to read the Microstation element attribute values from .Net C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, microstation

I am using following code for read the element attribute from index.But it shown the error like Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'MicroStationDGN.DataBlock[]'.Is there any problem in my code?

```
 private string readAttribute(Element ele,int attribIndex)
    {  
        String getStr = "";
        DataBlock[] dtBck = (DataBlock[])ele.GetUserAttributeData(attribIndex);
        if (dtBck.Length != -1)
        {
            dtBck[0].CopyString(getStr, false);
        }
        return getStr;
    }
```